# how to implement monthly repeating alarms at the last day of the month

Tags: java, android, android-alarms

I want to fire alarm at the end of every month. Currently, the code is working well as per the specified time, month and day - but it only works for the first month - for subsequent months it doesn't work.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

manager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);



if (currentMonth == Calendar.JANUARY || currentMonth == Calendar.MARCH || currentMonth == Calendar.MAY || currentMonth == Calendar.JULY
    || currentMonth == Calendar.AUGUST || currentMonth == Calendar.OCTOBER || currentMonth == Calendar.DECEMBER) {
    // calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,31);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);

    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

if (currentMonth == Calendar.APRIL || currentMonth == Calendar.JUNE || currentMonth == Calendar.SEPTEMBER
    || currentMonth == Calendar.NOVEMBER) {
    //  calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}

if (currentMonth == Calendar.FEBRUARY) {//for feburary month)
    GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    if (cal.isLeapYear(currentYear)) {//for leap year feburary month
        //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,29);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    } else { //for non leap year feburary month
        // calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,28);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}

Toast.makeText(this, "will start at 12:30am", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Are you running this class in background service ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add the new Alarm in your `AlarmReceiver` class.

Now you are triggering just a single Alarm that's why it works for one single month.

In your `onReceive()` method get the `AlarmManager` and set the new alarm for the next month.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer:* I don't know the `AlarmManager`, so this may not be a good answer, but I also wanted to show how the code can be improved.

It seems you want to run the code at 12:30 PM *(not AM like the last statement says)* on the last day of the month, but if you're past that time, e.g. at 1:15 PM, you end up setting the alarm to a time in the past, when you really need to set the time for end of *next* month.

Also, `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())` is redundant, because [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) just did that for you too:

> The Calendar returned is based on the **current time** in the default time zone with the default locale.

Similarly, calling `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth)` with the month you just extracted will do nothing whatsoever.

To find the last day of the month, call [`getActualMaximum(DAY_OF_MONTH)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)), instead of all those `if` statements.

So, all that `Calendar` code boils down to this, including the fix for being past the target time:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.clear();
cal.set(currentYear, currentMonth, lastDay, 12, 30);
if (cal.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // First of next month
    lastDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDay); // Last of next month
}
```

If you print the result using:

```
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

It give me this output:

```
Wed Nov 30 12:30:00 EST 2016
```

*Note:* If you wanted 12:30 AM, not 12:30 PM, just change the `12` to `0` in call to `set()`.